# Remove all values in a string before a backslash

Tags: regex, powershell, text-parsing, backslash, ends-with

I have this string

> AttendanceList
> XXXXXX
> US\abraham
> EU\sarah
> US\gerber

when i try to use `-replace` it replaces all characters inserted in square bracket (including the first line AttendanceList)

`$attendance_new = $attendance -replace "[EU\\]", "" -replace"[US\\], ""`
`echo $attendance_new`

> AttndancLit
> XXXXXX
> abraham
> arah
> grbr

i was hoping to get this sample output (and possibly concatenate a string "_IN" after all values)

> AttendanceList
> XXXXXX
> abraham_IN
> sarah_IN
> gerber_IN

I'm new to regex and still trying to figure out the regex code for special characters

Comment: Please clarify if you want to only match `EU` or `US` at the start of a line followed with a ``\`` char and then remove these values and add `_IN` to the end of these lines. Users [start thinking up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70763070/remove-all-values-in-a-string-before-a-backslash/70763115?noredirect=1#comment125099339_70763115) additional requirements or suggesting different logic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$attendance_new = $attendance -replace '(?m)^(?:US|EU)\\(.*)', '$1_IN'
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/m9GotV/1) ([.NET regex demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%28%3F%3AUS%7CEU%29%5C%5C%28.*%29&i=AttendanceList%0D%0AXXXXXX%0D%0AUS%5Cabraham%0D%0AEU%5Csarah%0D%0AUS%5Cgerber&r=%241_IN)). *Details*:

- `(?m)` - multiline option enabling `^` to match start of any line position
- `^` - line start
- `(?:US|EU)` - `EU` or `US`
- `\\` - a `\` char
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than a line feed char (**note** you might need to replace it with `([^\r\n]*)` if you start getting weird results)

Comment: the OP seems to want to remove ANY text up to & including the "\". so your regex pattern seems to be overly specific. i would use something like `'(?m)^.+\\(.+)', '$1'` instead.